# AWS Amplify PCI DSS Certificate

Tags: aws-amplify, pci-dss

I want to integrate a payment service in my web application but the service provider needs a PCI Certificate for my web application as to see the current situation I'm thinking to move my server on AWS Amplify since AWS is a PCI DSS Compliant so if I host my web app do I get a separate PCI Certificate from AWS which I can show to the payment service provider for the payment integration.
I'm confused if I used AWS Amplify do AWS provide me a PCI Certificate for my web application. Please elaborate me regarding this.
Thanks

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/services-in-scope/

Comment: Amplify is PCI-DSS compliant, but your app will not be. You need to prove that you are too, but you will not have to bother for any question related to the Amplify part. Look at PCI-DSS SAQ A